# Messaging / Triggering between WaIISHost and W3WP (Azure web role)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, azure, azure-web-roles

So I want the Webrole to react to Configuration changes, which involved capturing the event "Changing" and update a static dictionary (contains my Features setup)

Sounds like a simple task, it just I then realised that any changes made in the static object in WaIISHost (which handle the Changing event) is not accessible by the W3WP process.

I'm thinking of using either a message queue (using Azure queues) or Anonymous Pipe (but still don't know how to set that up)

Anyone knows how to either passon the Changing/Changed event from the WaIISHost process to W3WP, or if not possible, best way (i.e. least complicated) to communicate between the 2?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to the RoleEnvironment events from within w3wp.exe and then the events will be raised in both processes (w3wp.exe and WaIISHost.exe).  Global.asax is a good place to do this.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow never thought of this! Will try out and let you know